# sync existing oracle data base with Couchbase server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, couchbase-lite, xamarin.forms, couchbase-sync-gateway

We hope to implement Couch base Mobile for our mobile application to add the offline support.

Is it possible to sync our existing oracle data base with Couch base server.

Our mobile application developed using xamarin and it is a xamarin form application that support the ios, android and windows.

We want update existing oracle database with offline support.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what happens with Couchbase Mobile users is that they use the change worker pattern as refered here: http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/changes-worker/pattern/index.html

and also webhooks: http://blog.couchbase.com/sync-gateway-webhooks

This allow mobile users to integrate with external solutions like an Oracle database.